# Pause YouTube video on next slide with Flickity

Tags: javascript, youtube, carousel, flickity

I'm using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) to create a slider that contains both images, video and youtube embeds (using Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields [oEmbed](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/oembed/)).

I'm looking to pause the playing video on the flickity-event [select](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html#select) (next slide).

My code works with the video-embed, but I can't seem to pause the YouTube player.

There are multiple YouTube slides in the slider, within iFrames that Advanced Custom Fields don't allow me to give class names.

Simplifyed HTML structure:

```
<div class="carousel">
    <img src="image" />
    <div class="video"><video src="somevideo" /></div>
    <div class="video"><iframe>YOUTUBE-EMBED</iframe></div>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
$('.carousel').flickity({
    // slider options
});

var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity();
$carousel.on( 'select.flickity', function( event, index ) {
    $('.video').find('video').each(function() {
        this.pause();
    });
});
```

The pause function works with the embedded  but not the . Any ideas?

I have tried with:

```
    $('.video').find('iframe').each(function() {
        ytplayer.pauseVideo();
        this.pauseVideo();
    });
```

And

```
    if (ytplayer) {
        ytplayer.pauseVideo();
    }
```

...without luck

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: You probably don’t have any `ytplayer` instance here to begin with, you would need to create those first. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors

Comment: Sounds about right @04FS. Could you help me in the right direction of how to create the instance?

Comment: I thought I’d done that, by pointing you to the documentation, that even has examples …? If you need more than that, you need to describe what your specific problem is first. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Åsmund Sollihøgda's answer didn't work for me with multiple YouTube videos so I adapted it slightly and added auto play for the current video.

```
$slider.on( 'select.flickity', function( event, index ) {

            $('iframe').each(function( i, el ) {

                if( i == index ){
                    $(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'playVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
                } else {
                    $(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'); 
                }
                
            });   

        });
```

Comment: Ah but I did find one problem here, instead of `$slider.on( 'select.flickity',` it should be `$slider.on( 'change.flickity',` otherwise it will start playing the video every time you resize the window!  (Because apparently the slide is 'selected' every time you resize the carousel for some reason) https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html#select

Answer (score 0):

I used the advanced custom fields oembed settings like this to add "enablejsapi":

```
<?php
$iframe = get_sub_field('url');
// use preg_match to find iframe src
preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $iframe, $matches);
$src = $matches[1];
// add extra params to iframe src
$params = array(
    'enablejsapi' => 1
);
$new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
$iframe = str_replace($src, $new_src, $iframe);
// add extra attributes to iframe html
$attributes = 'class="youtube"';

$iframe = str_replace('></iframe>', ' ' . $attributes . '></iframe>', $iframe);

echo $iframe;
?>
```

Then I added this to the flickety-event:

```
var $carousel = $('.content-fields-carousel').flickity();
$carousel.on( 'select.flickity', function( event, index ) {
    $('.video').find('video').each(function() {
        this.pause();
    });
    $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');    
});
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
flkty.on( 'change', function( index ) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".video-slider__cell").forEach(videoSlideCell => {
        let videoFrame = videoSlideCell.querySelector(".video-slider__cell-video");
        if(document.body.contains(videoFrame)) {
            videoSlideCell.querySelector(".video-slider__cell-video").contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
        }
    });
});
```

With this Code you can handle the play and pause in multiple cells with pure Vanilla JS.
Replace my variables with your variables and it works just great!

Fo